# Generic type parameter narrowing when using it as index

Tags: typescript, generics, union

I have two values that are kinda complementary:

- first contains some functions
- second contains their arguments, stored at corresponding keys

You can see an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMCMC8MDeAoGMCGAXDABQEBOA5sWAgLYBGApuTAJToB8MokIANkwB0-EJTL4q7ADS4YDYhKrFo5AJZhK7Lj3AQBw0eIpa2svMEUniDEAfxhtabr32CRYpaewBfANzY2K6wkpSoGDh4RDAAjObyxADkMYnxljBQ5AhMvoHYiMhQauAwAF4APDAAKjBMAB5QTGAAJqgA1kwAniBwGZ0ADkw98EgoMJxkHZ3ENRyRI8gQANowUzAAul7Lq10b7H4wuYFkAPIMAFZMwFBCUxBkBSgc+KgAguTk+J2VU8NQA0Neo9UNw2EI6Ph+mQ1LBnGVobAOGw-EA):

What bothers me is that even though I use generic, compiler is not able to narrow types enough to understand that during the looping phase each function will be called with corresponding argument. As a result, js version works as expected, but I get compile time error.

Is there a way to get rid of that error in a correct way, rather than casting to any?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the mapping between the key and function, by building a discrimated union type.

```
    type funcType = {
      kind: 'a',
      f: ( arg: number ) => void,
    
    } | {
      kind: 'b',
      f: ( arg: string ) =>void,
    
    }| {
      kind: 'c',
      f: ( arg: boolean ) =>void,
    
    };
function z2< T extends keyof typeof args >( key: T ) {
  return funcs[ key ]; 
}
const test: funcType['f'] = z2('b');
```

Comment: I believe that doesn`t quite solve my issue